# EE 3.5.1 => Unable to upload file

Tags: ee3, file-uploads

When I try and upload an images (any kind), I getting this PHP error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Library\Mime\finfo_open() in /path_to_ee/backend/ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Library/Mime/MimeType.php:117 Stack trace: #0 /path_to_ee/backend/ee/legacy/libraries/Mime_type.php(106): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Library\Mime\MimeType->ofFile('/tmp/phpfeusnS') #1 /path_to_ee/backend/ee/legacy/libraries/Upload.php(172): Mime_type->ofFile('/tmp/phpfeusnS') #2 /path_to_ee/backend/ee/legacy/libraries/Filemanager.php(2042): EE_Upload->do_upload('file') #3 /path_to_ee/backend/ee/legacy/libraries/Filemanager.php(1083): Filemanager->_upload_file(Array, 'file') #4 /path_to_ee/backend/ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Controller/Files/Files.php(200): Filemanager->upload_file('1', 'file') #5 [internal function]: EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Controller\Files\Files->upload('1') #6 /home/jakecovert/wo in /path_to_ee/backend/ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Library/Mime/MimeType.php on line 117
```

I'm running EE version 3.5.1.

My PHP version is 7.0.27.  Any thoughts on what I can check?

Really appreciate any thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

With Dreamhost, I just had to add "extension = fileinfo.so" to my phprc file:

```
~/.php/7.0/phprc
```

Not sure why it got changed when they upgraded my VPS OS from Ubuntu 12 to 14.

:-)